# CSS: how to clip a div

Tags: css

We have the following `div` rotated 45 degrees, and shunted to the right to cut the corners off.

However, this allows the browser window to be scrolled to the right to see the overflow.

[Live website](http://www.tambreyvillage.com.au/).

How do we clip the overflow off, so that there is no scroll to the right?

Help appreciated.

```css
.degrees-45 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    background-color: #740000;
    padding: 1em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1.5);
}
.degrees-45 h3:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.degrees-45 h3 {
    padding: 1em 10em;
    color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 1961px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -43%; top: 60px}
}
@media (min-width: 1500px) and (max-width: 1960px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -43%; top: 70px}
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1499px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -30%; top: 40px;}
 .degrees-45 h3 {font-size: 17px;}
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1399px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -31%; top: 40px;}
 .degrees-45 h3 {font-size: 16px;}
}
@media (min-width: 790px) and (max-width: 1099px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -36%; top: 50px;}
 .degrees-45 h3 {font-size: 15px; padding: 0.5em 10em;}
}
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 789px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -42%; top: 40px;}
 .degrees-45 h3 {font-size: 14px; padding: 0.5em 10em;}
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -44%; top: 40px;}
 .degrees-45 h3 {font-size: 12px; padding: 0.5em 10em;}
}
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 479px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -50%; top: 30px;}
 .degrees-45 h3 {font-size: 11px; padding: 0.5em 10em;}
}
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 399px) {
 .degrees-45 {right: -53%; top: 20px;}
 .degrees-45 h3 {font-size: 9px; padding: 0.5em 10em;}
 .degrees-45 h3:first-child {padding-bottom: 1.25em;}
}
@media (max-width: 299px) {
 .degrees-45 {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<div class="degrees-45">
    <h3>Hungry Jacks &amp; Liberty Fuel<br>OPENING APRIL 2020</h3>
    <h3>Shopping Centre<br>OPENING NOVEMBER 2020</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
div#et-main-area {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It will apply `overflow: hidden` and take away that unwanted space.

Answer (score 1):

Try add attribute `overflow: hidden;` in the parent element

[image]